# view simple indexes on AppEngine Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore

How can I view the simple index definitions on Googles AppEngine Datastore? Is it possible at all?

There is a "Datastore Indexes" view which only displays the composite indexes as it seems (the ones you define in `datastore_indexes.xml`).

Comment: Just see your model definition

Comment: I have defined the index on my model, but it does not work. I wonder whether it has been applied correctly in the datastore. What happens for instance if you change the indexed elements after some had been persisted with the old model definition?

Comment: What do you mean by does not work? For non custom index, you should put the old objects to include them in the index.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by does not work? For non custom index, you should put the old objects to include them in the index.
From the doc https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/indexes

"Note, however, that changing a property from unindexed to indexed does not affect any existing entities that may have been created before the change. Queries filtering on the property will not return such existing entities, because the entities weren't written to the query's index when they were created. To make the entities accessible by future queries, you must rewrite them to the Datastore so that they will be entered in the appropriate indexes. That is, you must do the following for each such existing entity:"

Comment: I seemed to have a weird issue with AppEngine not building indexes or only very delayed I guess. Seems to work now fyi, but still thanks for the pointer. Guess the answer to my initial question is "No, not possible".

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible (yet) to view the simple index definitions on your datastore model.

The actual index in the datastore can vary between entity instances (if the definition was changed at a time where there already was data stored). Changing simple indexes thus requires a manual migration (read and put all data so it is stored and indexed again with the new definition). Thanks @marcadian for the pointer.